# Cordova Statusbar plugin gap

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

Trying to get to grips with using Cordova for hybrid app development and I'm really enjoying their plugins, making some task in JS a lot easier to manage.

However I'm having an issue with the Status bar plugin, got a dark theme on the app I'm playing around with, charcoal, dim orange colour and some greys so I'm insistent on using a dark status bar so I've used the status bar plugin, however when I install it it causes a gap between the start of content and status bar.

If i uninstall the plugin the gap disappears and the bar returns to default white but no gap.

in the config.xml I've set

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

in the JS on device ready function

```
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
```

If I set this to true the gap disappears but the status bar goes white and shows the battery icon and nothing else, false set the status bar to colours in the config  but the gap appears. I've also tried to hide and show it on load to get it to set right but no luck.

Not really sure how I can get it to sit right.

Comment: You'll have problems pushing your app to the store according to [apple](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/bars/status-bars/)

Comment: could you elaborate? will this help me in relation to the problem?

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer. Just mentioning it.

Comment: Okay well could you elaborate on why problems may occur when pushing to Apple Store?

Comment: Read the guidelines I sent in the first comment. And because of personal experience.

Comment: appreciate the comment, didn't see the guidelines attached, reviewing it I will most likely leave it as the default status bar seeing as this seems to be the only view which will render properly.

Comment: With cordova this is what apple wants `window.StatusBar.styleDefault();`

Comment: Yeah I've just been reading up on it, it seems to display properly now apart from iPhone X which I'm guessing its a different issue all together

Answer (score 1):

After reading some documentation & the link provided by a member in the link I've accepted that its best to please apple by leaving the status bar as default or not use the plugin at all.